# What to do with generated SOAP calls from a WSDL file in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm just starting out with Java, but my boss is pushing for this. I've taken the WSDL file we had, and generated a web service and a web client in Netbeans. Also, I've dragged the new service into my client and made sure, that the code works. But now I have a question. How do work with the result? The code in my JSP looks like this:

```
try {
    Soap.PDFSignatureServiceService service = new Soap.PDFSignatureServiceService();
    javax.xml.namespace.QName portQName = new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://external.ltc.com/", "PDFSignatureServicePort");
    String req = "<getTimestamp  xmlns=\"http://external.ltc.com/\"><msisdn>ENTER VALUE</msisdn></getTimestamp>";
    javax.xml.ws.Dispatch<javax.xml.transform.Source> sourceDispatch = null;
    sourceDispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, javax.xml.transform.Source.class, javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);

        javax.xml.transform.Source result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(req)));



        out.print(result.toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    out.print(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

The code works, but what it is printing out is: `com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.StAXSource@90fe8e`. What in the world do I do with this? I was expecting either a SOAP message, or an integer of some sorts. How do I get to somewhere from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here is creating a dynamic client and actually you are working on the *payload level* and not on the SOAP message level.

For the SOAP level you would have to do:

```
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch
```

The result in your case is the XML payload of the response.
You can for example **convert it to String** and see it:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();  
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();  
Result stringOut = new StreamResult(writer);      
transformer.transform(result, stringOut);  
writer.close();  
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Or convert it to XML node:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();  
DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();  
transformer.transform(result, domResult);  
rootNode = domResult.getNode();
```

Disclaimer:Did not even attempt to compile the code

Comment: So, what you are saying is, I'm only caring about the content, not the message WITH the content, am I right?

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Also, when printing with `System.out.println()` I see the complete message in the logs. But when I `out.print()` it, I see only the number it returns. Is that a feature of the servlet?

Comment: Nevermind, looked at the source, the rest of the message is there.

Comment: When you do `Dispatch<Source>` you are essentially saying that you will be working with the xml encapsulated in the `SOAP` envelope.You will not see the `SOAP` message itself.Only the xml message send directly by the server.If you use `Dispatch<SOAPMessage>` you are saying that you will be working at the `SOAP` level i.e. the response is the whole `SOAP` message that carries the servers xml response.Depending on what you need to do/process you use the related api.If you would need to work at `SOAP` level you would need the latter api

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Also, could you please point me to some resources to clear this whole thing up? I can't seem to make any sense of the automatic binding taking place in the project. Can't seem to figure out where the SOAP parameters are bound to the functions and where the values are passed on.

Comment: @Janis:See if this helps you http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0707_thaker/0707_thaker.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Dispatch.invoke specs in javadocs, it is :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Dispatch.html#invoke(T).

And if you change your code to :

`**javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource** result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(new java.io.StringReader(req)));`

The `StreamSource` has methods to get the Reader and eventually some meaningful result can b obtained.

Comment: I am getting this: `Unknown class type javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource`